# Windows script - run silent but wait for completion / return right code

Tags: windows, deployment, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-scripting

**Here's my situation:**

- I have a BAT file that takes a long time to run (1minute to 70 minutes)
- I schedule it with Windows scheduler to run every 10 minutes
- If it schedules again while it is still running, nothing happens (this is good)

My problem is that I need my BAT to run silently, and it doesn't.  So, I want to launch it with a Windows script like the following:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Unfortunately, when I schedule this script, it does the job but returns **instantly**, making Windows scheduler think the task is finished when in reality the BAT is just running off by itself somewhere.

Because of this, Windows will reschedule the job again 10 minutes later and make multiple run.

**What I need:**

Is there a way to tell the Windows script file to wait for the target of the .Run command to complete before progressing/exiting?  Basically, I want it to act like I launched another thread and then called join on it, so it does the same thing the BAT would have, but without displaying the console window.

**Other Solutions**

Tell me any other way to get this BAT to execute silently (powershell commands, whatever) and I'll accept it as a solution as well.  Just don't tell me to write a full on C++/C# appliation around it, that's overkill :)

---

**Running:** Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here goes the madness...

Create a file `invisible.vbs`:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, True
```

Then in the task scheduler, call your script like this:

```
wscript.exe "C:\Batch Files\invisible.vbs" "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat"
```

I tested it and this does really work: No command window, and the task is considered running until the batch script ends.

Credit goes to https://superuser.com/a/62646/40362.

---

For 2008 R2 make invisible.vbs have this content, and just execute it directly.  It will run the BAT silently and wait for completion.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "D:\IUpdateScript.bat", 0, true
```

Comment: I'll try both of these and select the one that works best :) Thanks.

Comment: This one doesn't quite work the way I needed.  It does run the process in the background, but the wscript.exe "C:\Batch Files\invisible.vbs" "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" call returns instantly which still means it gets double scheduled.  +1 for the help though I learned more :)

Comment: Not on my machine (win7 x64) - the scheduled task's status is _running_ until the batch file ends.

Comment: I guess I should have specified OS's.  On my windows 7 machine, Scheduled Tasks executing bat files do it hidden anyway on mine, so it wasn't an issue.  I'm deploying to Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and now I'm seeing the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

I think all you need is TRUE for the optional 3rd argument

```
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" & Chr(34), 0, TRUE
```

Comment: I'll try both of these and select the one that works best :) Thanks.

Comment: +1 thank you for the help, the sync true flag was definitely my first problem.

Comment: and how would I chain 2 bat files (or two separate commands) and wait for the first to finish?