# VBS script wait on return

Tags: powershell, vbscript

We're launching a PowerShell script with the help of vbs to avoid the pop-up it generates. This works flawlessly as you can see below:

`PS_Launcher.vbs`:

```vb
'run window totally hidden
Dim oSHELL
Set oSHELL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oSHELL.CurrentDirectory = "C:\users\bob\AppData\Local\Temp"
oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File .\PS_Script.ps1", 0
Set oSHELL = Nothing
```

The only problem is when we run this from within a scheduled task or from the command prompt (CMD), it doesn't wait for the PowerShell script to finish and immediately returns the prompt.

Is there a way to have it wait for the PowerShell script to finish before continuing?

We've tried the following as described in [`bWaitForReturn`](http://ss64.com/vb/run.html), but no luck:

```vb
oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File .\PS_Script.ps1", 0, True
```

`PS_Script.ps1`:

```bsh
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk |
    Select-Object Name, ProviderName |
    Export-Csv .\PS_Data.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It's one 100% sure VBScript, as the PowerShell script only contains `Start-Sleep -Seconds 15`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 2nd attempt where you included the `true` argument in `Run` should work.

The fact that the prompt returns immediately after running the script from command prompt doesn't mean that the script is not waiting, as the script runs in a different environment to `cmd`.

Take this example:

**PowerShell**

```bsh
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("powershell END")
```

**VBScript**

```vb
Dim oSHELL
Set oSHELL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File C:\test\test.ps1", 0, True
Set oSHELL = Nothing
MsgBox "vbs END"
```

Now whether I run the VBScript by double-clicking it or calling `test.vbs` from the command prompt, I see the expected results, i.e.:

1. Wait 5 seconds
2. Display `powershell END` message
3. Display `vbs END` message once the powershell message has been dismissed

However, when running it from cmd, the prompt returns to me as soon as I call `test.vbs`, even though the above steps are still completed correctly.

Perhaps you could try adding some message boxes like this in your scripts to help you track what is going on during testing.

Comment: We're starting the vbscript from the Task Scheduler. Found something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659456/windows-script-run-silent-but-wait-for-completion-return-right-code) that might help with keeping the task in status `Running`. Thx for the tips though!

Comment: @DarkLite1 The same applies. When I call my above vbs from a scheduled task it stays in `Running` status for 5 seconds - displays the powershell prompt, and then displays the vbs prompt. Which version of windows are you running, and did you try including message boxes in your scripts?

Comment: Make sure to run VBScripts with `cscript.exe` when you run them as scheduled tasks, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I noticed some discussion on that on a few forums, but my scripts seem to run the sme without calling through `cscript` - Do you know the implications of not including it? (I'm using Windows 10)

Comment: Indeed, when launched from the prompt it immediately returns the prompt. Bur from within a Scheduled Taks it works flawlessly and stays in status `Running`. Thank you very much. learned something new today.

Comment: @Bassie With `cscript.exe` regular output (error messages, `WScript.Echo`, ...) goes to STDOUT/STDERR instead of creating a popup message that blocks further execution.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers when creating a scheduled task with `cscript.exe` it shows a pop-up, this is not the case when using `wscript.exe`

Comment: I seriously doubt that. Please provide evidence.